# Density Function of Series Connection

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution, order-statistics

The random lifetime of a certain electronic component is given by- $ f_Y(y) = \dfrac{1}{a} e^{-(y/a)}, y>0 $. Two such components are connected in series. The system fails when the first component fails. We've to find the density function of RV $Y_{(1)}$, the lifetime of the system. How should I proceed with this problem?